# Azure available backup shows 'No databases found'

Tags: sql, azure, backup

I have created azure monthly backup retention policy for a Azure SQL database. It has been over a month. But i do not see any backup in available backups tab.

- Database: Standard S0: 10 DTUs
- Retention for: 2 yrs.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer can answer you question.

You have created azure monthly backup retention policy for a Azure SQL database.
And when you click on available backups you do not see the list of backups.
[image]

This might be related to a permissions issue on the subscription level. Basically, the LTR Backups are related to the subscription and not the server, so if the server was deleted those LTR backups would still exist as they are associated with the Subscription.

Now to give yourself permission to view and restore the LTR backups, please make sure that you have one of the following permissions on the subscription level:

1. Subscription Owner or
2. SQL Server Contributor role in Subscription scope or
3. SQL Database Contributor role in Subscription scope

Please note that you can grant permissions for your users using the PowerShell cmdlets, full tutorial can be found here: [I cannot see the Long-Term Retention (LTR) backups](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresqldbsupport/2018/10/23/i-cannot-see-the-long-term-retention-ltr-backups/).

If more granular control is required, you can create custom RBAC roles and assign them in the Subscription scope.

For `Get-AzureRmSqlDatabaseLongTermRetentionBackup` and `Restore-AzureRmSqlDatabase` the role needs to have the following permissions:

1. `Microsoft.Sql/locations/longTermRetentionBackups/read`
2. `Microsoft.Sql/locations/longTermRetentionServers/longTermRetentionBackups/read`
3. `Microsoft.Sql/locations/longTermRetentionServers/longTermRetentionDatabases/longTermRetentionBackups/read`

For `Remove-AzureRmSqlDatabaseLongTermRetentionBackup` the role needs to have thefollowing permissions:

```
Microsoft.Sql/locations/longTermRetentionServers/longTermRetentionDatabases/longTermRetentionBackups/delete
```

Now after you grant the required permissions to view the LTR backups on the Subscription level, you will be able to view them at the Avaiable Backups pane as shown in image 3 below.
[image]

Here is the Reference: [Unable to view LTR Backups for Azure SQL Database servers](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresqldbsupport/2018/11/13/unable-to-view-ltr-backups-for-azure-sql-database-servers/)

Hope this can helps you.